# Why does the Size increase but not Free space in cfdisk?

Tags: partitioning, disk, qemu

I'm running ubuntu in a VM on Unraid. I have increased the VM's capacity with:

```
qemu-img resize path/to/raw/img/vdisk.img +100G
```

After restarting I can see in the UI that the space has been allocated, but the capacity remains unchanged:
[image]

I was expecting after restarting to be able to see the extra space under Free space in cfdisk, but the Free space remains unchanged. However the system can tell the extra Space has been allocated, see `Size: 201 GiB`
[image]

Comment: You have increased the size of the underlying, raw, disk. Now, you must increase the size of the filesystem on th disk. Read `man resize2fs`.